# How to compare two variables using If Else in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

```
Var first
Var second
Section
   Strcpy $first "1.0"
   Strcpy $Second "2.1"
   ${If} $second > $first
     MessageBox MB_OK "Grater"
   ${Else}
     MessageBox MB_OK "Smaller"
   ${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

I have written the above code but it is showing me result as smaller. And how to compare a integer or double value coming from a text file with a predefined double or integer value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [LogicLib](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LogicLib), You may compare two integers like this:

```
Var first
Var second
Section
   StrCpy $first 1
   StrCpy $Second 2
   ${If} $second > $first
     MessageBox MB_OK "Grater"
   ${Else}
     MessageBox MB_OK "Smaller"
   ${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

with capital **C** in `StrCpy`. Also try removing quotes (`"`) from numbers to make them integers.

Another way would be this:

```
Push $first
Push $Second
StrCpy $first 8
StrCpy $Second 2

IntCmp $first $Second Equal Val1Less Val1More

Equal:
    DetailPrint "$first = $Second"
    Goto End
Val1Less:
    DetailPrint "$first < $Second"
    Goto End
Val1More:
    DetailPrint "$first > $Second"
    Goto End
End:

Pop $Second
Pop $first
```

Comment: Yeah even I tried this one also, still it is showing me the same answer. Is their any other way to compare two numbers in nsis?

Comment: Thanks friend. The second answer is working fine. Now I'm able to compare two integers. But when I Push float numbers then it gets fail. Can you tell me how to compare two floating numbers??

Comment: as Anders mentioned correctly, NSIS does not support floating point numbers in the basic instructions

Comment: Okay. Can I use VersionCompare to compare two floating numbers?

Comment: I don't think so. that is not what `VersionCompare` is intended to work

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I check the type of a value return from powershell?     (I use ${If}  $a ==1 ${EndIf} , it's wrong. I use IntCmp, it's true)

Answer (score 1):

NSIS does not support floating point numbers in the basic instructions, you need to use the [Math plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Math/Math.txt) that is part of the default install...